# Is FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS the only FileVisitOption available?

Tags: java, io, nio

I see that the only constant available is `FOLLOW_LINKS`. On the other hand there is the method `FileVisitOption.values()` which returns an array of `FileVisitOption` values. I wonder, if it only has FOLLOW_LINKS what's the need of having a method that returns an array of values(which values?).

The API of this class is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's an `enum.` It can't help having the `values()` method. It's generated by the compiler.

Might have more values one day.